# Browsers sending AJAX request 3 times

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, google-chrome

All my browsers (Chrome 15, Firefox 5) sending 3 requests on the one action - button or link click (with remote attribute, of course). Maybe I have a few bindings, but application has just 2 included js files:

```
= javascript_include_tag :application
= javascript_include_tag 'rails'
= javascript_include_tag 'jqueryui'
```

Application generated by template https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber has nothing unusual.
Additional gems (except https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber/blob/master/Gemfile ):

```
gem "devise", ">= 1.4.2"
gem "frontend-helpers"
gem "rails-footnotes", ">= 3.7", :group => :development
gem 'thin'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'formtastic'
```

Solved.

Comment: [Gazler](http://stackoverflow.com/users/219743/gazler) said: "you can visit the url with ?debug_assets=1 to see all the files it is loading. " So i could find all includes and remove extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you have precompiled your assets (javascripts)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

You have only one line to include:

```
 = javascript_include_tag :application
```

since XX century.