# jquery:install doesn't work in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed gem `jquery-rails` in Rails 3.1 app. But line below

```
rails generate jquery:install --ui
```

Getting error:

```
Could not find generator jquery:install.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In rails 3.1, because jquery is the default, you no longer need to install it, it will be required in app/assets/jquery/application.js and it will look something like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

You can verify which generators are available by executing rails g without anything else:

```
rails g
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But now i`m back to previous problem that requests sending 3 times. I`d asked it in another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089522/browsers-sending-ajax-request-3-times), but now i see, that it happens only with default jquery. When i had added it manually, there was only one request. Do you know something about this issue?

Comment: Since rails 3.1 combines all your assets, you can visit the url with ?debug_assets=1 to see all the files it is loading.  In 3.1 you should use requires like the code sample above instead of multiple javascript_include_tag calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, it was included a few times. I had decrease it by one removing "require_tree ." and second by removing "rails.js" file. But maybe i`ll need it? What am i going to do in this case?

Comment: You probably still have `jquery.js` in your project; you don't need it anymore, the `require jquery` line above will use the version in the `jquery-rails` gem. The gem also includes `jquery_ujs.js`, which is a replacement for the `rails.js` file that was used prior to 3.1. So, delete the jquery.js file and rails.js file, and you can put back the `require_tree .` statement.

Comment: Thanks. So, there was no need to do any.

Answer (score 0):

for Rails 3.0.x application do the below steps,

- Add gem “jquery-rails”, “~> 1.0.13″ in your Gemfile, and run bundle
  install
- run the command rails generate jquery:install --ui --force, it will remove  prototype.js, effects.js, dragdrop.js, controls.js
  and create  jquery.js, jquery.min.js,  jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui.min.js, jquery_ujs.js

to use jquery functions add the below lines in the application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```